# C Buffer overflow - Return address not expressible in ASCII

Tags: c, stack-overflow, exploit, stack-smash

I'm trying to overflow a buffer of 64bytes.
The buffer is being filled by a call to `gets`

My understanding is that I need to write a total of 65 bytes to fill the buffer, and then write another 4 bytes to fill the stack frame pointer.
The next 4 bytes *should* overwrite the return address.

However, the address that I wish to write is `804846A`.

- Is this same as `0x0804846A`? If so, I'm finding it hard to enter 04 (^D)
- Should this be entered in reverse order? (6A 84 04 08)?

  - Some initial experiments that I was running with input being ZZZZZ..(64 times)..AAAABBBB
    ended up making the `ebp` register to be `0x42414141`

The architecture in question is x86.

**update:** I managed to get ASCII codes `0x04` and `0x08` working. The issue seems to be with `0x84`. I tried copying the symbol corresponding to `0x84` from http://www.ascii-code.com which is apparently `„`. However, C seems to resolve this symbol into a representation greater than 1 byte.

I also tried to use `ä` as mentioned in http://www.theasciicode.com.ar
This also resulted in a representation greater than 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be depending on implementation details of a particular compiler and CPU architecture. For example:

- Not all CPU architectures use a frame pointer at all.
- Endianness varies across different CPUs, and this would affect whether you need to "reverse" the bytes or not.
- Where the stack metainformation (the frame pointer, etc.) is located with respect to a given local variable will differ between compilers, and even between the same compiler using different optimization options.

Comment: How would I insert ASCII control character 0x04? I'm able to represent the rest of the address except for this byte.

Comment: If you mean by typing at a console, then the problem you're running into is that the shell interprets `^D` to mean "flush stdin" or "close stdin" (depending on context). If you want to force the shell to treat it literally, then (by default) you can escape it with a `^V`. You can also remap it with a tool like `stty`.

Comment: I tried it with `^V`..but it seems to produce some unexplainable results. `0x08048464` is being translated into `0x9e80e264` when using `d„^D^H`..I guess I will try to use `stty`